PowerShell Script Downloading Corrupted exe File
I am trying to download the Adobe Acrobat installer using a URL, but the script consistently downloads an almost empty exe file (something around 4 KB in size), and my system keeps telling me the file is corrupted and unreadable.
I am wanting to properly download the installer, so I can run it, and perform a full install of Adobe Acrobat this way. I've tried different methods such as Invoke-WebRequest, using curl, using start bit transfer, but nothing works. I've verified the URL I'm using is legit as I put it in my web browser and it downloaded the Adobe Acrobat installer just fine. Here is the PowerShell script that I am currently using:
$adobeInstallerUrl = "https://get.adobe.com/reader/download?     os=Windows+10&name=Reader+2024.003.20112+English+Windows%2864Bit%29&lang=en&nativeOs=Windows+10&accepted=cr&declined=mss&preInstalled=&site=landing"

$installerPath = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Reader_en_install.exe"

function Download-AdobeInstaller {
    Write-Host "Downloading Adobe Acrobat Installer from $adobeInstallerUrl ..."
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $adobeInstallerUrl -OutFile $installerPath
        Write-Host "Download complete. Installer saved to $installerPath"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to download Adobe Acrobat Installer. Error: $_"
        exit 1
    }
}

function Install-AdobeAcrobat {
    Write-Host "Running Adobe Acrobat installer..."
    try {
        Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -ArgumentList "/sAll /rs /rps /msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES" -Wait
        Write-Host "Adobe Acrobat installation complete."
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to install Adobe Acrobat. Error: $_"
        exit 1
    }
}

function Verify-FileSize {
    $file = Get-Item $installerPath
    if ($file.Length -lt 1000000) { # Assuming the file should be larger than 1MB
        Write-Host "The downloaded file is too small and might be corrupt."
        exit 1
    }
}

Download-AdobeInstaller
Verify-FileSize
Install-AdobeAcrobat


The big space in the URL for $adobeInstallerUrl is not meant to be there and it is not there in my script on my PC.

You need to recover the actual status code returned by the web server, and look at what it has actually sent you. If Adobe are defending against bots and scrapers then it's possible you're getting a 403 (Forbidden) code, and your output file contains a corresponding message.

Your url isn't a binary download - it's a html page that kicks off the download process when you load it in a browser. When you request the contents of that url in PowerShell you just get the raw html because Invoke-WebRequest doesn't contain the functionality of a full interactive web browser. You'll need to work out what that page is doing to get the browser to trigger the download and then update you script to do that instead...

Consider using winget it also has a PowerShell module named Microsoft.WinGet.Client.

Sorry, I got myself confused in the original form of my answer. Please see my update, which contains instructions on how to determine the true download URL yourself, as well as command that uses it, which should work as-is.

mclayton has provided the crucial pointers in a comment:

The target URL causes Invoke-WebRequest to download an HTML page, rather than the binary (executable) of interest.

When opening this URL in a web browser, it is the JavaScript embedded in that HTML that triggers a download interactively.

With Invoke-WebRequest / Invoke-RestMethod, all you get is the HTML source code, which won't help you.



To determine the true download URL, you can initiate a download interactively in a browser and monitor the network activity, which will reveal the true download link; in a Chromium-based browser (Chrome, Brave, Microsoft Edge), you can do this as follows (works analogously in other browsers):

Open your original URL, https://get.adobe.com/reader/download?os=Windows+10&name=Reader+2024.003.20112+English+Windows%2864Bit%29&lang=en&nativeOs=Windows+10&accepted=cr&declined=mss&preInstalled=&site=landing, in your browser.

If prompted to confirm the download, cancel the dialog. (In Microsoft Edge the download will occur instantly, so you'll have to clean up the downloaded files later.)

Right-click anywhere in the document and select Inspect to open the web inspector. In it, select the Network tab, then click on Fetch/XHR to filter the activity being monitored.

Refresh the page (Ctrl+R), and if the confirmation dialog pops up again, cancel it again.

Now look for a line matching *.exe in the activity list (should
be readerdc64_ha_cra_install.exe), right-click on it and select Copy > Copy URL to copy the URL to the clipboard.





You can now use the copied true download URL with Invoke-WebRequest, with an -OutFile file name/path of choice:
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile Reader_en_install.exe 'https://admdownload.adobe.com/rdcm/installers/live/readerdc64_ha_cra_install.exe'

